# FullCalendar lib with LockerService

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I know a lot of people are having the same problem but I'll go along and ask. I use ltng:require to import the fullcalendar js lib. Ever since the lockerservice was activated I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
>   throws at /resource/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js

I used to have the fullcalendar.min.js working alright w/o LockerService, but now I get that message. I changed from fullcalendar.min.js to fullcalendar.js as suggested in another question but does not work for me.

Does it mean that I have to wait for this library to be checked and allowed by salesforce? Any known workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

No you do not have to wait or change libraries as long as the problem is in LockerService we'll get it fixed before mandatory activation happens. Salesforce is not in the per library checking or allowing business though - LS has a [set of requirements that all javascript regardless of author must meet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm) and as long as those requirements are met we'll make sure our bugs in LS are resolved.

What we do need from you is a case (please post the case ID here) with repro info (post that here too please) etc so we can dig into the issue and see where the problem is. We're fixing bugs in LS every day and next weeks patch for Tues/Wed has a 6 very important fixes wrt issues discusovered with various libraries but not specific to any library. For example Leaflet.js is now working nicely but the fix for the symptom manifested by Leafletjs actually corrected the databinding issues also reported on stack exchange.

Comment: We are planning to use fullcalendar library with Lightning component but itdoesn't work in Napili Template after activating locker service. It works when the locker service is deactivated. We raised a case with Salesforce and thy said "JS library still needs to meet the strict mode compliant." But [Fullcalendar should work](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162225/which-external-js-libs-work-with-lightning-locker-service).