# full calendar issue in salesforce communities lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I am using full calendar plug in in my lightning component and is using the same in salesforce communities

once the script is loaded i am pulling the data from task and event object and assigning it to respective div and those div i have displayed as none during page load.I have 2 buttons there and i want on 1st button click i will show div1 but it is not happening.The calendar itself is not loading.Not sure where i am missing out

component code

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="FullCalendarController" access="global">
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/FullCalendar1/fullcalendar-3.1.0/jquery-2.2.4.js,/resource/FullCalendar1/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.js"  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}"/>
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/FullCalendar1/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.css"/>

    <aura:attribute name="events" type="Object[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Tasks" type="Object[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Contacts" type="Object[]"/>
    <aura:method name="sampleMethod" action="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" 
      description="Sample method with parameters"> 
    </aura:method>
    <div class="slds-col slds-medium-size--1-of-6 slds-large-size--1-of-6 back_div">
                    <div class="slds-tabs--default">
                        <ul class="slds-tabs--default__nav" role="tablist">
                            <div id="TAB1">
                                <li id="add_class_div" class="slds-tabs--default__item slds-is-active">
                                    <a class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset"  tabindex="0" id="tab-default-1__item" onclick="{!c.ShowEvent}" >
                                        <p class="para_div"><div id ="assetnew1" class="assetnew_div" >Event</div> </p> </a></li>
                            </div>
                            <div id="TAB2">
                                <li id="add_class_div2" class="slds-tabs--default__item" role="presentation">
                                    <a class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tab-default-2" 
                                       id="tab-default-2__item" onclick="{!c.ShowTask}" >
                                        <p class="para_div"><div id ="orgnew1" >Task</div></p></a></li>
                            </div>

                            <div id="TAB3">
                                <li id="add_class_div4" class="slds-tabs--default__item" role="presentation">
                                    <a class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tab-default-4" 
                                       id="tab-default-4__item" onclick="{!c.ShowTask}" >
                                        <p class="para_div"><div id ="orgnew2">Medication</div></p></a></li>
                            </div>
                        </ul>           
                    </div>
                </div>
    <div id="calendar" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="calendar1" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="calendar2" style="display:none;"></div>
</aura:component>
```

controller code

```
({
    afterScriptsLoaded: function(cmp,evt,helper){

        var events = cmp.get("v.events");
        console.log('Community Calender Event is : '+events);

        if(!events.length)
        {
            helper.fetchEvents(cmp);
        }

        var tasks = cmp.get("v.Tasks");
        console.log('Community Calender Task is : '+tasks);

        if(!tasks.length)
        {
            helper.fetchTasks(cmp);
        }

        var contacts = cmp.get("v.Contacts");
        console.log('Community Calender contacts is : '+contacts);

        if(!contacts.length)
        {
            helper.fetchcontacts(cmp);
        }

    },

    ShowEvent : function(component, event, helper){
        debugger;
        document.getElementById("calendar").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("calendar1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("calendar2").style.display = "none";
        //debugger;
        //alert('111');
        var events = component.get("v.events");
        console.log('Community Calender Event is : '+events);
        if(!events.length)
        {
            helper.fetchEvents(component);
        }
        //alert('22');
    },
    ShowTask : function(component, event, helper){
        document.getElementById("calendar").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("calendar1").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("calendar2").style.display = "none";
    },
    ShowContact : function(component, event, helper){
        document.getElementById("calendar").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("calendar1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("calendar2").style.display = "block";
    },
})
```

//helper code

```
({
    loadDataToCalendar :function(data){ 
     //var ele=component.find('test').getElement();
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },

            editable: true,

             events:data,

               eventClick: function(event) {
                   //alert(event.url);
                   console.log('event url:'+event.url);
                    }   

        });

    },

    loadDataToCalendar1 :function(data){ 

        $('#calendar1').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },

            editable: true,

             events:data,

               eventClick: function(event) {
                   //alert(event.url);
                   console.log('event url:'+event.url);
                    }   

        });

    },

    tranformToFullCalendarFormat : function(component,events) {
           console.log('eventArr length-->'+events.length);
        var eventArr = [];
        for(var i = 0;i < events.length;i++){
            eventArr.push({
                'id':events[i].Id,
                'start':events[i].StartDateTime,
                'end':events[i].EndDateTime,
                'title':events[i].Subject,
                'url':'/PatientPortal/s/event/'+events[i].Id

            });
        }

        return eventArr;
    },

    tranformToFullCalendarFormatTask : function(component,events) {
        console.log('eventArr length task-->'+events.length);
        var eventArrTask = [];
        for(var i = 0;i < events.length;i++){
            eventArrTask.push({
                'id':events[i].Id,
                'start':events[i].ActivityDate,
                //'end':events[i].End_Time__c,
                'title':events[i].Subject
                //'url':'/PatientPortal/s/event/'+events[i].Id
            });
        }

        return eventArrTask;
    },

    fetchEvents : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getEvents"); 
        var self = this;
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
                var eventArr = self.tranformToFullCalendarFormat(component,response.getReturnValue());
                console.log('eventArr--->'+eventArr);
                console.log('eventArr length fetch--->'+eventArr.length);
                if(eventArr.length >= 0)
                {
                    self.loadDataToCalendar(eventArr);
                    component.set("v.events",eventArr);
                }
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    },

    fetchTasks : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getTasks"); 
        var self = this;
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
                var eventArrTask = self.tranformToFullCalendarFormatTask(component,response.getReturnValue());
                console.log('eventArr tasks--->'+eventArrTask);
                console.log('eventArr length fetch tasks--->'+eventArrTask.length);
                if(eventArrTask.length >= 0)
                {
                    self.loadDataToCalendar1(eventArrTask);
                    component.set("v.Tasks",eventArrTask);
                }
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    }
})
```

it looks like on button click document.getElementById("calendar").style.display is not working.It is not able to render the full calendar.

Comment: have you tried debugging, are there any errors in the console, what does the network tab say?

Comment: You've not posted the code for the helper class that's referenced. Also, you have an uncommented `debugger;` on the 1st line below the `ShowEvent : function` that would seem to be problematic.

Comment: there is no error in the console and I have removed the debugger statement as well but still no luck

Comment: Is the locker service turned on ? if not Turn off your locker service critical update .. for more info on the issue, refer : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172224/locker-service-and-fullcalendar-io